# Using php to send Text messages without SMS gateway provider

Tags: php, sms

We are wanting to use PHP and the mail function to send many Text messages a day, we are talking thousands. Is this a reliable way to it? Our hope is that we will not need to use an SMS gateway provider. Will there be any faults to just using plain PHP to send these text messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We are wanting to use PHP and the mail function to send many SMS messages a day, we are talking thousands. Is this a reliable way to it?

No. You'd need to special case each network, and I'd expect "thousands of messages a day" to get treated a spam.

> Our hope is that we will not need to use an SMS gateway provider.

How else do you expect to get data from the Internet onto the SMS network?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase that. We want to send thousand of "text" messages using only php and not resorting to an SMS gateway provider

Comment: You need an SMS gateway provider by definition. Either you pay for a proper one, or you depend on the various free email-to-sms services provided by the cellular networks (which I would expect to react to "thousands of messages a day" by flagging them as spam and discarding them).

Comment: Either way, you have to use gateway in one way or another.

Comment: Understood. I meant not using a commercial gateway provider, that is all I meant. But I now see they would probably be marked as spam.